# Pretty URL via separate folder and index.html file inside or rule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, nanoc, pretty-urls, static-site

I have static site (html + css) generated by nanoc.
It works under Apache.

I want use pretty url instead of .html suffix at the end. Like this:

- http://domain.ru
- http://domain.ru/page/page1/
- http://domain.ru/page/page2/

instead of

- http://domain.ru/index.html
- http://domain.ru/page/page1.html
- http://domain.ru/page/page2.html

So, the 1st way is to create the separate folders with names page1 and page2 and place inside index.html files with corresponding content. When client does request:

http://domain.ru/page/page1/   is loaded file  page1/index.html

The 2nd way is to have such files structure:

page (folder)

- page1.html (file)

- page2.html (file)

and create rule for .htaccess file in root of the site:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1.html

So, the question is which way is better ? May be there are some additional costs of using 
rewrite rules or pitfalls? May be there are some good practices for this questions for static generated sites.

PS:
In any way i use .htaccess file: i need switch on utf-8 encoding, enable 404 error handling , disallow browse folders

Thanks and sorry for bad english :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use `index.html` in directories, because it is server -independent. I don’t think there’s a good reason not to do it that way.

Comment: Agreed. It also means, if you need something simple but dynamic, you can enable PHP on your server and drop an `index.php` in there too, and it Just Works™ :)

Comment: Thanks. i did with separate folder. also it gives a possible place some page related resources (as images for ex.)  in this folder.